# Migrations of Procedure in mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server, nestjs, typeorm

I have a project using `nestjs` and `typeOrm` on the backend. I want to change a `Procedure` in `MSSql` database. How can I do that with migrations? I couldn't find any solution for `Procedures`, only for tables. Can anyone tell me please how to do that?

Comment: Would you be so kind to clarify,what you mean under " I want to change a Procedure in MSSql database. How can I do that with migrations?".

Comment: @Sergey I'm new to this. We have a procedure used in database. I have a task to change that procedure using backend and migrations. I don't know how can I do that.

Comment: OK.  Stored procedure  is SQL-code stored inside database.You can change it in any text-editor and save it back to database

Comment: @Sergey so I have no availability to do it like updating tables using migrations?

Comment: Sorry, but in my opinion it would be better if you clarify this task with your customer.

Comment: @Sergey I was told to make change in database procedure. I have no access to that DB. So he said I need to add that change to migration and use that hen build an app for production.

Comment: aha. Could you please tell me the following: do you have a text of the stored procedure?

Comment: @Sergey i have an example only. There I should add some piece of code.